# Print all surrounding coordinates given an X and Y

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I want to make a function that given a list and a range:

```
coordinate=[x,y]
```

Creates a list that contains all integer points in range.
For example,

```
coordinate=[0,0]
range=1
```

Would return

```
[[-1,1],[0,1],[1,1],[-1,0],[0,0],[0,1],[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1]]
```

Likewise for range 2 would return

```
[[-2,2],[-1,2],[0,2]...]
```

Comment: Nice idea, what do you have already?

Comment: What have you tried already, and what are your thoughts? I don't want to do your homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def coord(x,y,range_of_search):
    scan=range_of_search
    blank=[]
    for i in range(x-scan,x+scan+1):
        for j in range(y-scan,y+scan+1):
            blank.append([i,j])

    print(blank)
coord(0,0,2)
```

I got it, didn't think of appending a list at once. I was appending individual elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with an accordant `range`. Speaking of `range`, you should select some other name for your `range` variable, e.g. `dist`.

```
>>> coordinate = (x,y) = (0, 0)
>>> dist = 1
>>> [(x+dx, y+dy) for (dx, dy) in itertools.product(range(-dist, dist+1), repeat=2)]
[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

If you want the exact same ordering as in your example output, try this variation:

```
>>> [(x+dx, y+dy) for (dy, dx) in itertools.product(range(dist, -dist-1, -1), range(-dist, dist+1))]
[(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list-comprehension:

```
>>> ranges = 1
>>> [[y, x] for x in range(ranges, -(ranges + 1), -1) for y in range(-ranges, ranges + 1)])
[[-1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [-1, -1], [0, -1], [1, -1]]
>>> ranges = 2
>>> [[y, x] for x in range(ranges, -(ranges + 1), -1) for y in range(-ranges, ranges + 1)])
[[-2, 2], [-1, 2], [0, 2], ...]]
```